# Simplifying trignometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

How does the denominator on the left become the denominator on the right. When I try to simplify it, I get $-2\cos^2(\theta)+2\cos \theta$. What am I doing wrong... please help.
[image]

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, but you must first please check what you have simplified is the same as what is given in the R.H.S. (take $2\cos \theta$ common).

Comment: Will do next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1-\cos^2 (\theta) = (1+\cos(\theta)) (1-\cos (\theta))$

$1-2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta) = (1-\cos(\theta))^2$

$\therefore (1-\cos^2 (\theta))-(1-2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)) = (1-\cos (\theta))(1+\cos(\theta))-(1-\cos(\theta))^2 = (1-\cos (\theta)) [1+\cos(\theta)-(1-\cos(\theta))] = ((1-\cos(\theta))(2\cos(\theta))$